# Animated 3D Button - Opera jQuery hover Bug & transition-delay font-family Bug

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

Hello stackoverflow community. Great to be here this is my first posts so lets get started :)

I created my own Pen [3D Animated Buttons](https://codepen.io/t33n/pen/yXwZVx)

```
stackoverflow want the full code but it will be to long to post here
```

I faced 2 problems:

First of all. Yeha I know that the JS code could be also done in CSS but because I had the font-family transition problem I created the jQuery part.

First I wanted to add a transition delay to the font-family change on the button hover but I can´t use : font-family .2s ease; | transition: font-family .2s; | transition: font-family 2s; | transition-delay: font-family 2s; or anything else like that.. The font-family will be always changed directly.
So this was the reason I used jQuery to add a timeout. What you guys think should I do for font-family transition delay with pure css?

And the second problem is that the basic jQuery hover function and the mouseover function is not working for me in Opera. as example

```
$(".test").hover(function () {
alert('test');
},
function () {
});
```

That was the reason I created this extra css code only for opera. all other browsers can use the jquery hover code above.

```
.fake_id_realflipbutton1:hover #id_realflipbutton1 {
transform:rotateX(360deg);
border: 5px solid #fff;
font-size:19px;
color:#222222;
transition: all 1.6s;
font-family: 'Audiowide', sans-serif;
}
```

Here is button 1 in html, css and js. Maybe it will be better if you watch the live pen to understand or look the sample code here for the first button.

```js
 // BUTTON 1
    $(".fake_id_realflipbutton1").hover(function () { ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $('head').append('<style class="style_1_wait">#id_realflipbutton1{font-family:\'Roboto\', cursive !important;}</style>'); // <-- WORKAROUND FOR OPERA BUG
    $('head').append('<style class="style_1">#id_realflipbutton1{transform:rotateX(360deg); -webkit-transform:rotateX(360deg); -o-transform:rotateX(360deg); -moz-transform:rotateX(360deg); -ms-transform:rotateX(360deg);}</style>');
    $('#id_realflipbutton1').css('border', '5px solid #fff');
    $('#id_realflipbutton1').css('font-size', '19px');
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('head').append('<style class="style_1_wait">#id_realflipbutton1{font-family:\'Audiowide\', cursive !important;}</style>');
    $('head').append('<style class="style_1_wait">#id_realflipbutton1{color:#222222}</style>');
    }, 600); // <-- 600 should be smooth time - try to adjust by yourself if you don´t like :)
    }, //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function () {
    $(".style_1").empty();
    $('#id_realflipbutton1').css('border', '1px solid #fff');
    $('#id_realflipbutton1').css('font-size', '15px');
    setTimeout(function(){
    $(".style_1_wait").empty();
    }, 633); // <-- 633 should be smooth time - try to adjust by yourself if you don´t like :)
    }); // $("#id_realflipbutton1").hover(function () {
```

```css
     /*#######################################################*/
    
    body {
    background-color:grey;
    }
    
    /*  START - BUTTON 1   */
    
    .div_1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 55px;
    top:50px;
    }
    
    
    #id_realflipbutton1 {
    width: 200px;  /*orig: 200px*/
    height: 55px; /*orig: 55px*/
    z-index: 1337;
    display: block;
    border: 1px #fff solid;
    transition: all 1.6s;
    
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #fff; /*<- set the color of the border without hover*/
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: rgba(13, 7, 7, 0);
    }
    
    
    .fake_id_realflipbutton1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 55px;
    }
    
    .fake_id_realflipbutton1:hover #id_realflipbutton1 {
    transform:rotateX(360deg);
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    font-size:19px;
    color:#222222;
    transition: all 1.6s;
    font-family: 'Audiowide', sans-serif;
    }
    
    
    #id_realflipbutton1::before, #id_realflipbutton1::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    content: '';
    z-index: -1;
    margin: -5%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px;
    -webkit-animation: clipMe1 8s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation: clipMe1 8s ease infinite;
    -o-animation: clipMe1 8s ease infinite;
    animation: clipMe1 8s linear infinite;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 1.6s;
    }
    /*  END - BUTTON1   */
    
    
    
    /*  ______________________________________________________  */
    
    
    
@keyframes clipMe1 {
    0% {
    clip: rect(0px, 0px, 0px, 0px);
  }
  50% {
    clip: rect(0px, 200px, 220px, 0px);
  }
    75% {
    clip: rect(0px, 220px, 220px, 218px);
  }
   100% {
    clip: rect(0px, 0px, 0px, 0px);
  }
 } /*@keyframes clipMe1 {*/ 

@-webkit-keyframes clipMe1 {
    0% {
    clip: rect(0px, 0px, 0px, 0px);
  }
  50% {
    clip: rect(0px, 200px, 220px, 0px);
  }
    75% {
    clip: rect(0px, 220px, 220px, 218px);
  }
   100% {
    clip: rect(0px, 0px, 0px, 0px);
  }
 } /*  @-webkit-keyframes clipMe1 {  */ 

@-moz-keyframes clipMe1 {
    0% {
    clip: rect(0px, 0px, 0px, 0px);
  }
  50% {
    clip: rect(0px, 200px, 220px, 0px);
  }
    75% {
    clip: rect(0px, 220px, 220px, 218px);
  }
   100% {
    clip: rect(0px, 0px, 0px, 0px);
  }
 } /*  @-moz-keyframes clipMe1 {  */ 

@-o-keyframes clipMe1 {
    0% {
    clip: rect(0px, 0px, 0px, 0px);
  }
  50% {
    clip: rect(0px, 200px, 220px, 0px);
  }
    75% {
    clip: rect(0px, 220px, 220px, 218px);
  }
   100% {
    clip: rect(0px, 0px, 0px, 0px);
  }
 } /*  @-o-keyframes clipMe1 {  */ 

/*_____________________________________*/
```

```html
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="Animated 3D Flip Buttons with Laser,Glitch Effects & Text Transform [CSS+JS] - created by Dennis Demand | www.hornyfamily.online">
  <meta name="author" content="created by Dennis Demand | www.hornyfamily.online">
  <title>Animated 3D Flip Buttons with Laser, Glitch Effects & Text Transform [CSS+JS]</title>
  

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!--  Button 1  -->
    <div class="div_1">
    <div class="fake_id_realflipbutton1">
    <button id="id_realflipbutton1">Button 1</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code is very messy. clean up/minimise your css.. don't put absolute positioning in classes.. add it in an extra class if necessary, there are online css minifiers that may assist you. That's without even touching the js! oh and btw, i'm using chrome and don't see a problem (your codepen says there's a problem with chrome) .. what's the problem? the buttons flip..

Comment: just checked it in opera.. works there also. pls post code without it having been pre-adjusted-for-opera; then it would be much easier to assist you

Comment: I know minify/compression tools, but that´s not the point but anyway thank you for the tip. When you hover as example on button 6 you will get render bugs with chrome/opera/safari. you see the glitches? Maybe it´s not for everybody but I sended the link to friends and they see it also.

"pls post code without it having been pre-adjusted-for-opera"
In opera jQuery hover function or mouseover function is not working. Imagine the clear basic functions that you use.Its not working for me in opera. I can only use :hover. So the question was why are this jQuery functions not working with opera.

Comment: also hold the hover it only comes at the end. wait until animation complete you will see the bug. in firefox will it be clear at the end no black lags

Comment: this is maybe a version problem then, as I see no difference at all

Comment: I make now a code snippet with only only button 1